# i wanted to catch the error and reinput the number

Tags: c#

iam very new to C# programming. I wanted to catch the errors for example invalid input (not a number from 1-5) and print out a message stating the error and reinput the number. This is my code.

```cs
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("              Silahkan Pilih Jumlah Penarikan   ");
Console.WriteLine("               ---------------------------                                ");
Console.WriteLine("                  ----------------------           ");
Console.WriteLine("1.100000");
Console.WriteLine("2.300000");
Console.WriteLine("3.500000");
Console.WriteLine("4.1000000");
Console.WriteLine("5.Jumlah lain");

           
                    switch (Console.ReadLine())
                    {
                        case "1":
                            if (currentUser.getBalance() < 100000)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Saldo tidak mencukupi :( ");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                currentUser.setBalance(currentUser.getBalance() - 100000);
                                Console.WriteLine("sisa saldo anda = " + currentUser.getBalance());
                                Console.WriteLine("Terimakasih :)");
                            }
                            break;
                        case "2":

                            if (currentUser.getBalance() < 300000)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Saldo tidak mencukupi :( ");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                currentUser.setBalance(currentUser.getBalance() - 300000);
                                Console.WriteLine("sisa saldo anda = " + currentUser.getBalance());
                                Console.WriteLine("Terimakasih :)");
                            }
                            break;
                        case "3":

                            if (currentUser.getBalance() < 500000)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Saldo tidak mencukupi :( ");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                currentUser.setBalance(currentUser.getBalance() - 500000);
                                Console.WriteLine("sisa saldo anda = " + currentUser.getBalance());
                                Console.WriteLine("Terimakasih :)");
                            }
                            break;
                        case "4":

                            if (currentUser.getBalance() < 1000000)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Saldo tidak mencukupi :( ");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                currentUser.setBalance(currentUser.getBalance() - 1000000);
                                Console.WriteLine("sisa saldo anda = " + currentUser.getBalance());
                                Console.WriteLine("Terimakasih :)");
                            }
                            break;
                        case "5":
                            Console.WriteLine("Masukan jumlah penarikan Tunai yang anda inginkan");
                            Console.WriteLine("            (dalam kelipatan 100000)         ");
                            double penarikan;
                            while (true)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    penarikan = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                    if (penarikan % 100000 == 0)
                                    {
                                        if (currentUser.getBalance() < penarikan)
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine("Saldo tidak mencukupi :( ");
                                            Console.WriteLine("Silahkan coba lagi ");

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            currentUser.setBalance(currentUser.getBalance() - penarikan);
                                            Console.WriteLine("sisa saldo anda = " + currentUser.getBalance());
                                            Console.WriteLine("Terimakasih :*");
                                            break;

                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Nominal yang anda masukan salah. Silahkan coba lagi ");
                                    }
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Nominal yang anda masukan salah. silahkan  coba lagi");
                                }

                            }
                            break;
                           
                    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# How to loop user input until the datatype of the input is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996793/c-sharp-how-to-loop-user-input-until-the-datatype-of-the-input-is-correct)

Answer (score 0):

Usually logic in this case laid out like this

```cs
bool hasValidValue = false;

while (!hasValidValue)
{

    string val = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (val)
    {
        case "1":
            DoSomething(val);
            hasValidValue = true;
            break;
        case "2":
            DoSomething2(val);
            hasValidValue = true;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("invalid value");
            break;
    }
}
```

in other words - you loop until you get the valid value in